# Unity C# TCP socket timeout in non-local

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, networking, portforwarding

**Context :** 
I'm trying to connect a client and server in unity using C#. It works well on my local network (with my ip 192.168.1. ...). Now, I want to connect through my router, in non local. I forwarded a port from my router to my desktop ( the 16500th).

**Problem :** 
When I enter my router ip instead of my local ip, the socket timeouts (I don't know if it's the server not responding correctly or the client not connecting...).

**What I tried :**
I used this forwarded port in Java (with my router ip), with a chat software of mine, and it works well. So the problem may not come from the forwarded port.

**Server Code :**

```
public class TestServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestClient testClient;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 16500);
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(Accept), null);
        testClient.Connect();
    }

    void Accept(IAsyncResult _result)
    {
        Debug.Log("client received");
    }
}
```

**Client Code :**

```
public class TestClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("91.173.89.92", 16500);
    }
}
```

**Precision** : I am not an advanced  programmer in networking.

Thanks guys in advance for any help.

**SOLUTION :**

It doesn't work if the server is launched from the editor : you have to build the project.

Comment: Any firewall blocking the port? also instead of `null` wouldn't you rather pass in the `listener` (see example of [`TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient))

Comment: @derHugo I'll look toward a firewall, but it worked in java and in local, so apparently it's not this. Passing in the listener doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure the Java app is closed before using c#.  Only one TCP connection can have the same three properties 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port Number.  There should be no reason that the JAVA (using a TCP connection) would work and TCP fail unless the connection already existed or the server (listener) was not running.

Comment: Yeah I made sure before posting that all you said was ok ( I knew about this). The Java app was rightly closed. Still thanks